# How does component observer change when the ember service variable changes

Tags: ember.js, service, ember-data, ember-cli, ember-components

I have a service with a variable "players" which is an array. Whenever the service variable changes, i want to compute a variable in another component. I have used **observer** and **computed property** but the component observer is not getting called or changed.

```
**roster.js:**
export default Ember.Service.extend({
    players:{},
});


**component.js:**
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  positions:config.APP.POSITIONS.cricket,
  roster: Ember.inject.service(),
  newPlayers: Ember.computed('roster.players',function(){
    console.log("Am the computed value"); 
    //This return statment is just an example that i want to change the result object
    return "am in "+this.get('roster').players.length
  }),
});


**component.hbs**
<div class="listview">
  <div class="player-list-panel">
   Length: {{roster.players.length}}
   New Players: {{newPlayers}}
  </div>
</div> 
{{yield}}
```

for the first time when page loads the component then the the **newPlayers** is called. When the players object in the service gets updated then the **newPlayers** is not getting computed

Please help me in how to get it or the right approach.

Comment: I think you are confusing the with term observer and computed property in your question, actually you haven't used observer, observer syntax is `Ember.observer('dependantKeyName',function(){ })`

Comment: In the question i gave example of computed value , I also used observer but that also didnot work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the component, to access service, you need to inject it. suppose service file name is `my-service.js`

```
myService: Ember.inject.service(),
```

`newPlayers`- is a computed property, You need to use it (ie, get it) somewhere in the code either in component js/hbs, only then this will be calculated otherwise it won't.

Comment: Did you use `newPlayers` in template ?.please create post your code hbs too. and what you tried. if possible share ember-twiddle that will be easy to debug.

Comment: How do you change service `players` object that is important, since you defined computed dependant key based on `players`, so when you replace with new object using `set` only then computed property will be recalculated again.

Comment: I am setting the player object using set method only

Comment: `players` you are treating it like array, but defined as `{}`, where are setting it ?. show us the code, I guess the problem is with dependant key. if you could provide simple verifiable minimum example in twiddle, it will be easy solve it.

Comment: hey Thanks!! the change in service players object is the issue. I was using the set method but dont know why it didnot work. Now i tried to redo it from first. then it worked. Thanks a lot